# Refused to apply style from "css-file-path" because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, nopcommerce

I upgrade Nopcommerece 4.30 to 4.50.1 from that day  I am facing the below issue on all pages of  my website  http://www.smmotors.org

"Refused to apply style from "css-file-path" because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled"

Please guide how to solve this issue i am struck.

[img][https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoXbL.jpg[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoXbL.jpg%5B/img%5D)

Thanks
Use the browser Dev Tools (F12) to check  script errors

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions of the bundles directory (wwwroot/bundles). IIS user must be able to write to this folder. Also, usually the Event Viewer provides helpful details which can explain what went wrong.

Comment: Yes its the (wwwroot/bundles) issue . 
Thanks